# What's the point of React's createContext factory function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

Why doesn't it work like so:

```
class AppProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {};

    render (){
        <React.Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</React.Provider>
    }
}
```

...

```
class AppConsumer extends React.Component {
    state = {};

    render (){
        <div>
            <h1><React.Consumer>{context => context.toString()}</React.Consumer></h1>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

...

```
<AppProvider>
    <AppConsumer>
        <AppConsumer>
        </AppConsumer>
        </AppConsumer>
        </AppConsumer>
    <AppConsumer>
    <AppConsumer>
    </AppConsumer>
</AppProvider>
```

The only use I can think of for having the factory function is declaring a `defaultValue` that consequent Consumers use - for testing, as the documentation says.

- But, I think that's actually a bad pattern, I'd prefer to simply get an error if there's no provider above my consumer...
- The proposed format is much simpler to grasp.

The confusing bit for me was, you can use the exact same context, but with two providers with different values in different places, so it's not really one shared context...

Comment: With this API, if you had a `Provider` inside another `Provider` (e.g. a 'theme' context wrapping your router's context, or vice versa), how would the `Consumer` know which context you were trying to access?

Comment: Als, note that if your component only needs to access a single context, there's a [simpler API you can use](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype), and if you're using React hooks, it's just as simple to [access multiple contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).